# Users can't find website

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a very odd problem:
I have a new site, hosted on Hostgator and built with wordpress.
I pointed the domain to the server about a month ago, so it has already propagated.

The problem is that some users, well a lot actually, just can't find the website.
when using Google Chrome they get the message: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find the site: www.nocturno.co.il. Did you mean: www.nocturno.org?"
As you can see in this image:
[image]

(its in Hebrew, but I guess you get the drift)

But some users, including myself, can see the site.
I even tried a few tests and they came out fine:
http://leafdns.com/index.cgi?testid=212253D0

I tried telling them to clear their browser's cache, and flush their DNS cache but that didn't work.

I'm guessing its DNS related but I'm really clueless, and I really need some help.
I couldn't find anything like this on any forum.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You might also want to see if the people having trouble are all coming from a particular ISP or geographical region.  Hostgator has allegedly been blocked in the past by various places, like eBay:

http://forums.ebay.com/db2/topic/Ebay-Partner-Network/Hostgator-Being-Blocked/510201248
http://forums.ebay.com/db2/topic/Ebay-Partner-Network/Sites-On-Hostgator/520014222

and China:

http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/will-my-website-work-in-china

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I've checked that already, and it's from different ISP's. I don't think it's geographically, since I can see it, and the others that can't are in the same country as I am (although different cities - but it's a very small country), and I have used hostgator before. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your DNS server, as you rightly supposed. I pointed [DNSCheck](http://dnscheck.iis.se) at it and it shows the following result:

> No SOA record found for www.nocturno.co.il.
>
> No SOA record was found when querying the name server. This is most probably due to a misconfiguration at the name server - a zone must have a SOA record.

Here's an example of what a SOA record can look like:

```
example.com            IN SOA  myserver.example.com. hostmaster.example.com. (
                            2014020401 ; serial
                            28800      ; refresh (8 hours)
                            7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                            604800     ; expire (1 week)
                            86400      ; minimum (1 day)
                            )
```

Some clients will be kind enough to resolve your site anyway, but a lot of them won't. Fix it and the problem should go away.

Answer (score 1):

I looked for the site and i can certainly see this site. I don't there is any DNS related issue in this case. However, since some uses cannot see this page, I would ask them to do the following checks

1. On windows, check the C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file and see whether any static entries are there for this site.
2. Ask the users whether they are behind any proxy server. There IE settings should have settings for accessing external pages if they are behind any proxy server. If they are behind a proxy server, the next thing to check is whether any related setting is there for the website.
3. Ask them to ping the website (ping nocturno.co.il) and see where replies they get. \
4. Ask them to use nslookup command from MS-DOS for www.nocturno.org and check what answers 
   they get. The answer section should have something similar to this

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns2.netureza.com.   86400   IN  A   81.92.212.24

I would take the above actions as a start.

This page http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/12/13/what-to-do-when-your-website-goes-down/#more-75513 is very useful to understand your issue.